# Single or multiple column index on date columns best for performance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

In SQL Server 2000, is it better to create an index on `start` and `end` date columns combined or one index on each one? MySQL handles multiple column indexes in a way that would most likley work fine with both columns in a single index. But I'm unsure how SQL Server handles this.

The idea is to search on a record where the `enddate > GIVEN_DATE` and also sometimes using `startdate < GIVEN_DATE AND enddate > GIVE_DATE`.

Since the table I will be adding the index to is quite large and will take some time and keep our system offline during that time I ask here before so I don't have to redo the procedure later ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to create one INDEX on fields ENDDATE + STARTDATE.  In this case MS SQL can use this index in queries

```
.... where ENDADATE > somedate
```

and on queries

```
.... where ENDADATE > somedate and  STARTDATE < otherdate
```

But keep in mind that this index will not be used in queries like

```
.... where STARTDATE < somedate
```

Comment: Just noticed `Index Filegroup` when creating the index. What does it refer to and how are these handled? Does it have something to do with WHERE the index is stored?

Comment: You can place your index in the different filegroup (file) and place this file on different physical disk on the computer.